# Weird 404 with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is partially a "this does not work" question, but also a best practices question in regards to URL beautification.

Here is a simplified site map:

- index.php
- / requests

  - .htaccess
  - students.php
  - corporate.php
  - districts.php
- rest of site

Like i noted above, I placed my .htaccess inside the requests directory. Here is a little background and what I am looking to accomplish:

The students and corporate pages will be customized for each school district participating in this program. Links will be distributed that will take them to their specific page. If someone attempts to visit the corporate or student pages without a district identifier - they are rerouted to districts.php where they can choose the school district they belong to.

This all works perfectly, however - I am trying to clean up my query strings, and would like **mysite.com/reqeusts/students.php?district=7** to look like **mysite.com/reqeusts/students/7**

Here is the .htacces file I am working with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule    ^students/([0-9a-z\-]+)/?$    students.php?url=$1    [L]
```

I can visit **mysite.com/requests/students.php** and **mysite.com/requests/students.php?district=7** perfectly fine, but **mysite.com/requests/students/7** gives me a 404.

**Here are my two questions:**

1. Is there anything that is obviously wrong with my current approach - everything I have read (here and externally) has led me to create what I have now, and looks to be working for most people.
2. Is this scalable? I would also like to handle query strings for corporate.php and districts.php as well, and most examples I have seen of this have only handled requests for one script.

**EDIT**
Mike pointed out in the comments that my `.htaccess` was pointed at student.php when the file was actually students.php - after making that switch, I can no longer access students.php at all - with or without a query string, beautified or not.

Comment: Your `RewriteRule` refers to `student.php`, but your map refers to `students.php`

Comment: The `RewriteCond` is suspect... That should not be necessary, and will in fact only match if a query string is present, which it won't be for your pretty url.

Comment: @MikeW Ah - you are right - although now that I made the change in .htaccess - I can't access students.php at all anymore. Alone, with a query string, or at /students/7

Comment: Otherwise, this is a very straightforward rewrite: `RewriteRule ^student/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ student.php?url=$1 [L]` no RewriteCond necessary

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski My initial issue was with the pluralization of students.php - after that, it locked down the entire directory - I 404 no matter how I try to visit students.php - even after making your changes and nixing the `RewriteCond`.

Comment: @anwyatt 404 for the whole dir seems strange too and I wonder if there's a problem elsewhere. Any unseen rewrite rules? Any .htaccess in a higher directory?  If you comment out the rewrite rule, can you access files directly?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Scratch that - I can access other files in that directory - I just can't get to students, no matter how I structure the URL.

Comment: @anwyatt And you have verified that this .htaccess is the cause by commenting out that `RewriteRule`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Just did - it looks like some of my issues have been due to caching - I can access the page as long as there is no query string now, it appears. This is in multiple browsers - after clearing the cache.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski and magically it works - no clue why. I hate .htaccess